# When do my tools consume durability?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Looking for a source on what exactly consumes durability on tools such as:

- Fishing poles
- Bug Nets
- Axes
- Shovels
- Watering Cans

And not tools, with no durability, such as the Ocarina, Vaulting Pole, and the Ladder.

Basically:

- Do misses consume durability?

  - Player character whiffs, hitting nothing but air
  - In the case of the fishing rod, character performs the action but does nothing if not close enough to water.
- Do trivial actions consume durability?

  - Hitting an NPC in the face with an axe, shovel, net
  - Hitting any non-action item with an axe, shovel, net (such as hitting a building, or a non-farmable rock)
  - Watering an NPC with the watering can, or just watering anything that isn't a flower
  - Using a shovel to dig up dirt (but not anything that isn't dirt, like Fossils, Flowers, Trees, etc.)
  - Using a shovel to fill in holes
  - Using a shovel on a rock that has already yielded the daily items

Answer (score 3):

- Axe: Consumes durability when hitting a tree(even if you don't get any wood), no other times.
- Shovel: Anytime you hit a rock, or when digging holes to dig up flowers, trees, fossils, or other buried goods. Not when digging holes with nothing in them.
- Slingshot: Hitting balloons out of the sky. Hitting other things or missing will not count.
- Fishing Rod: When catching fish or trash. No other times.
- Bug Net: Catching bugs. Missing or hitting people does not count.
- Watering Can: Not currently completely understood. It seems like not watering anything for a day is worth one flower, and missing a flower is worth one tenth of watering a flower.

Comment: Does this imply that striking rocks with the axe does not consume durability?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: What axe did you test with? Because stone axes do lose durability when used against rocks.

Comment: I did not personally test this instead sourcing it from this article.
https://www.polygon.com/animal-crossing-new-horizons-switch-acnh-guide/2020/3/31/21194209/durability-list-broken-breaking-shovel-axe-fishing-rod-watering-can-slingshot-bug-net

Comment: I also confirm that my stone axe broke against a rock.